# Programmatically remove watermarked text from image

Tags: php

I am developing a web application using php and I need to process thousands of images which are watermarked. How do I remove the watermarked text programmatically from the image and save them?

Comment: You could try to reverse the effect of the watermark if you have the original image of the watermark that was used.

Comment: Iit's *theoretically* possible to subtract the overlay from the image if you have the watermark in its pure form. But that's a very tough task to do individually for one image alone - it's going to be nigh impossible to automate.

Comment: @Pekka & @Gumbo: I actually was going to say that in my answer, but it's really a moot point. The OP will just see the "possible" part, and ignore the rest...

Comment: Plus, I'm not sure the result would be great, depending on the quality of the picture.

Comment: Write a Gimp plugin, not a PHP script.

Answer (score 3):

Visual recognition - as in the case of differentiating a watermark from the rest of an image - is in the domain of artificial intelligence, and it requires A LOT of neural network training.

If you can write a perfect algorithm for this one, you can break any CAPTCHA too. So good luck if you manage to do it! That said, you might be way over your head on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, this is impossible. That's the point of watermarks.

Comment: Impossible is a strong word. Several centuries ago, people didn't think we can travel to the moon.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you are correct. However, this is the sort of thing where "If you need to ask how, you probably can't do it."

Answer (score 1):

Images with watermarks got them for a reason (Often due to copyright).

Removing them can lead their author to sue you.

That said, you can't do it automatically or/and programaticaly. If you really need to remove them, do it manually and buy Photoshop­©

Comment: don't buy photoshop. use gimp.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone can remove the watermark of the image by just putting a simple code, then what is the use of firstly putting them on the images?  It is of no use if anyone can easily remove it.

It can be removed by image editing by tools like Photoshop etc. But that will make you violate  the copyrights law of the image owner. If you really need that image, request the owner via email or something.

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to remove. Try to guess the link without watermark 
Ex:

watermarked
http://domain.com/36436/34fdhfh_wtm.jpg

no watermark 
http://domain.com/36436/34fdhfh_nwm.jpg

:) of course it is not that simple (depends on the website owner) but somehow there might be a rule though